# how to replace nth character of a string in a column in r

Tags: regex, r, string, dataframe, gsub

My input is

```
a<-c("aa_bbb_cc_ddd","ee_fff_gg_hhh")
b<-c("a","b")
df<-data.frame(cbind(a,b))
```

I want my output to be

```
a<-c("aa_bbb-cc_ddd","ee_fff-gg_hhh")
b<-c("a","b")
df<-data.frame(cbind(a,b))
```

please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use sub,

```
sub("^([^_]*_[^_]*)_", "\\1-",df$a)
```

Example:

```
> a<-c("aa_bbb_cc_ddd","ee_fff_gg_hhh")
> b<-c("a","b")
> df<-data.frame(cbind(a,b))
> df
              a b
1 aa_bbb_cc_ddd a
2 ee_fff_gg_hhh b
> df$a <- sub("^([^_]*_[^_]*)_", "\\1-",df$a)
> df
              a b
1 aa_bbb-cc_ddd a
2 ee_fff-gg_hhh b
```

Answer (score 8):

If things are as consistent as you show and you want to replace the 7th character then `substring` may be a  good way to go, but you made the column character by wrapping with `data.frame` without `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.  You'd need to make the column character first:

```
df$a <- as.character(df$a)
substring(df$a, 7, 7) <- "-"
df

##               a b
## 1 aa_bbb-cc_ddd a
## 2 ee_fff-gg_hhh b
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a general way to replace the *n*th occurrence of `_` with `-`.

```
n <- 2

# create regex pattern based on n
pat <- paste0("^((?:.*?_){", n - 1, "}.*?)_")
# [1] "^((?:.*?_){1}.*?)_"

# replace character
sub("^((?:.*?_){1}.*?)_", "\\1-", df$a, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "aa_bbb-cc_ddd" "ee_fff-gg_hhh"
```