# How to gsub second character in a row

Tags: r, gsub

I am trying to gsub the second character in a row. I feel like I am close but I can't seem to figure it out. I tried reading about it and looking at other examples. I can't seem to figure it out

Here is what I am trying

```
df3 <- c("ATG")
df4 <- gsub('^.{0,2}', 'A', df3)
df5 <- gsub('^.{0,2}', 'T', df3)
df6 <- gsub('^.{0,2}', 'G', df3)
df7 <- gsub('^.{0,2}', 'C', df3)
```

This is what I want the output to looks like

```
AAG
ATG
AGG
ACG
```

but the output currently looks like this

```
AG
TG
GG
CG
```

I feel like I am close but I can't seem to figure it out

Comment: `do.call(paste0,c(as.list(strsplit(df3,'(?<=.).',perl=T))[[1]],list(c("A","T","G","C")))[c(1,3,2)])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
gsub("^(.).{1}", "\\1A", df3)
```

The `(.)` gets the first character as a group to extract - matches up with the `\\1`.
Then the `.{1}` gets the next single character.

Comment: Note this is really a duplicate of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31761627/how-to-replace-nth-character-of-a-string-in-a-column-in-r) - I've just applied it to your use case.

Comment: What you wrote works great but I am still not picking up on exactly is being done here. What would you write if you wanted to change the third character?

Comment: You could do: `gsub("^(.{2}).{1}", "\\1A", df3)` -  essentially it says find a pattern of "at the beginning, (a group of 2 of any character), one more character", then replace it with "(the group), A"

Comment: A great website for practicing regex is [https://regexr.com/](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am new to all of this so that is a great resource

Answer (score 2):

Does is have to be `gsub`?

`substr` makes in easy to get the second element

```
substr(df3, start = 2, stop = 2).

substr(df3, start =  2, stop = 2) <- "A"
```

Assign the desired character.

Comment: you could do `\`substr<-\`(rep(df3,4),2,2,c("A","T","G","C"))` or even `sapply(c("A","T","G","C"),\`substr<-\`,start=2,stop=2,x=df3)`

Comment: Both of those work great as well. I like the sapply @Onyambu